# Find the maximum value of an expression

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a,b,c$ be real and  positive and $a+2b+c=4$ then find the maximum value of $ab+bc+ca$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=2$, $b\rightarrow0^+$ and $c=2$.

Hence, $ab+ac+bc\rightarrow4$.

We'll prove that it's a supremum, for which we need to prove that
$$ab+ac+bc\leq4\left(\frac{a+2b+c}{4}\right)^2$$ or
$$(a+2b+c)^2\geq4(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$(a-c)^2+4b^2\geq0.$$
Done!

The maximum does not exist.

Comment: If "positive" in the question means "non-negative", the maximum exists and it is achieved at $a=c=2$ (with $b=0$).

Comment: @mlc I think a positive number can not be equal to zero.